# Need matlab help to construct a numerical example for solving system of linear equation for random matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am reading [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300396001804)(page 183). In this paper the iterative methods for computing some solution of the general restricted linear equations 
\begin{eqnarray}
Ax = b, ~~~~ x\in R(A^{k})~~~~ b\in R(A^{k})...(1)
\end{eqnarray}

where matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $k = index (A)$ and $R(A)$ denotes the range space of the matrix $A$.

The following iterative method for computing soluition of $(1)$ is given:

\begin{eqnarray}
x_{k+1} = x_{k} + \beta A^{k}A^{*k+1}( b- A x_{k}), ~~~~ k = 0, 1, \ldots
\end{eqnarray}
where, $\beta$ is a non zero real scalar such that $0<\beta < \frac {2}{\lambda_{max} ( A^{k+1}A^{*k+1})}$, $\lambda_{max}$ denote the maximum eigenvalue, $A^{*}$ denotes the transpose of the matrix $A$ and 
 starting with any initial approximation $x_0\in R(A^{k})$.

I need matlab code to solve system (1) for the random matrices. I am not able to generate matlab code such that conditions $x\in R(A^{k})~~~~ b\in R(A^{k})$ satisfies.

Here is the my matlab code

```
B =  rand(10, 5);
    A = B*B'; (random singular matrix of rank 5)
k = 2 (k = index(A) = 2)
 C = A'
 Y = A^2*C^3
 c = norm(A^3*A');
   beta =1.9/c;

 x0 = (not able to construct random vector x0 such that x0 belongs to R(A^2) );
 b = (not able to construct random vector b such that b belongs to R(A^2));
 I = eye(10);
 iter = 0
 f = 1
 g = 1
 maxiter = 500

 while  (f > 1.0e-6)&&(iter < maxiter)
     x1 = x0 + Y *(b - A*x0)
       iter = iter+1

     g = norm(A*x0 - b, 2)
        f = norm (x1- x0, 2)

     x0 =  x1
     ans = A*x1
 end
```

I have edited this question.

Thank you very much for your time and help. I would be very much grateful for any help.

Comment: Just a comment to the lines of the code containing "not able to": a random vector in a column span of $A^2$ can be generated, e.g., simply by `A*(A*randn(n,1))`.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thanks for the comment. Could you explain me how vector $A*(A*randn(n,1))$ lies in a column span of $A^2$? I would be very much thankful to you. You may instead write in form of answer. I need this much help only.

Comment: $x\in R(A)$ iff there is $y$ s.t. $x=Ay$, right?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thank you very much. I got your point. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure your implementation is correct. I do not have access to the reference, but 
$$
\left||(I - Y A)\right|| > 1
$$ for most random matrices, so your iteration won't converge.

Also, *ans*, is a reserved keyword in Matlab, so you should avoid using it, as it is volatile.

That said, the command to generate x0 and b are

```
x0 = A*A*rand(length(A),1);
b=A*A*rand(length(A),1); % generates vectors in R(A^2)
```